# showing visio diagrams in asp.net/html web page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visio, flowchart

i was wondering if there is a way to show VISIO diagrams(interactive/non-interactive) on asp.net/html web page. i have browsed through the web, but was not able to get any useful stuff. first of all is this possible and has any one done this previously. not worried about if it is interactive or non-interactive diagram.

Comment: I don't know if what you're asking for is possible, but I typically export the diagrams as JPEG when I need to do this, since not everyone who needs to access them has VISIO installed.  You may be able to get around that limitation if your users install the Visio Viewer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21701

Comment: Update: See if this helps.  I'm not posting it as an answer because it would be a link-only answer, but thre's code for using hte object tag to do this.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768041(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Does this have to be about Visio files (there is a free Visio file viewer available from MS), or is this just about visio-like files? General diagramming libraries are available for HTML/Javascript, however most of them do not support full Visio import.